# Cplex Decision Expression value limit

Tags: optimization, cplex, opl

I have a decision expression in cplex opl,

dexpr float A = x[i]-b[i];

And i want A take values of 0 and bigger, what would be the syntax to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [maxl()](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.10.0/ilog.odms.ide.help/OPL_Studio/opllang_quickref/topics/tlr_oplf_maxl.html) function is used for this purpose:

```
range I = 1..2;
dvar float+ x[I];
dvar float+ b[I];
dexpr float A[i in I] = maxl(x[i] - b[i], 0);
```

However, depending on how you use `A` it might be better to use a decision variable rather than a decision expression. Assuming your model is formulated so that `A` will always take values as small as possible (for example because non-negative values are penalized in the objective function) then you can use `dvar float+ A[I]` and add a constraint `forall(i in I) A[i] >= x[i] - b[i]`. This will implicitly make sure that `A[i]` is always the maximum between 0 and the difference. In some cases this can lead to more efficient solver behavior.